# KDB - Mapping a column to a table using timestamps

Tags: kdb

Imagine two kdb tables, (t1) is recording tick data (security prices from diff sources, i.e. multiple columns) with a timestamp, (t2) is recording trades with a timestamp.

My goal:

Append a column to t2 such that it will, for each timestamp in t2, extract the value from one column in t1 where the timestamp is closest to (or matches) the timestamp in t2. So I almost want to map the value of a certain column in t1 to t2 based on the timestamp.

I appreciate this is a bit convoluted but was thinking there might be a way other than running a query for each entry in t2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it might be helpful to consider an as of join:

```
aj[`sym`time;t2;t1]
```

Assuming the records are sequenced by the time column in both tables, this command will return the row in t1 which is in effect “as of” the time in t2.
Specifically, for a given time value in t2, the match picks the greatest time in t1 less than or equal to the given value in t2.

For further reading, please refer to https://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#aj-aj0-ajf-ajf0-asof-join

Comment: Thanks fella, that does work. One other thing, what is the " `sym " meant to represent (I left it out and it worked) and is it possible to formulate this using q sql?

Comment: The first argument of aj takes a list columns which are common to tables t1 and t2. The result of the join is then a table which contains a single column for each of these matching columns. As of joins are most commonly used to join trade and quote tables, which have matching sym columns, so I included "`sym" in the example above, but this must of course be modified for the particular tables you are working with

Comment: Understood. And, apart from the "join-columns", is it possible to select output columns from each table? I.e. if i don't want the entire table joined but just specific columns

Comment: In that case you could use a select statement on the table returned from the as of join. For example, if you only wanted the time and price columns you could use ```select time,price from aj[`time;t2;t1]```